# Kibana showing different data on different visualizations for same condition or query

Tags: elastic-stack, kibana-5

I have applied Kibana monitoring on **S** server. I am getting logs, set fields and everything seem to working fine. Now Pie Chart that I made for **S** Server response code, showing **519** *404 hits* while on server for today there are only **117** *404 hits* for today. **I already ensured that I am seeing data for today as well as for S server only and no Server else**.

Then to further drill down what going wrong, I make data table. When I don't add timestamp filed or disable it, then no of 404 response code shown as

[Kibana-error-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbJWT.png)

Now when I added timestamp field then 404 shown only on 3rd page and nowhere else and this way

[kibana-error-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmHEk.png)

This sort of 404 shown not match with server and even not matching in different visualizations. Please help me to understand where problem lies and how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem actually lies in your buckets filtering wherein you have split by rows. If you actually click on the Split Row button you can see there is a Size element which has been specified as 5. If your order is set as descending then, as per this it will give you the top 5 count results for a response as per timestamp.

So currently, the 2nd image which you have attached shows only the top 5 count per timestamp for each corresponding responses.

Hence, you can check for every response such as 404,200,300,301 etc (as received in Image 1), you will be getting only the top 5 count per timestamp for each responses in the 2nd image as you have attached.

**Note: Due to top mentioned as 5 even in Image 1 which you have specified, it displays the top 5 responses as per count. There could be more responses as received which you can check by changing size from 5 to 10.**

Comment: Thanks for answer. I get point. Kibana form buckets internally in which it classify data, and if size is set 5 then kibana just show 5 entries of bucket sorted in descending order. But can you tell how kibana make internal buckets? Is this random, pre-fixed or something else?

Comment: Internal Bucketing is not random, what it actually does is aggregate the metrics for the field similar to a GROUP BY field in SQL.